# How to find if a word in a sentence is pointing to a city

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

How to find if a word in a sentence is pointing to a city

I live in San Francisco
I work in San Jose
I was born in New York

Is there a way to find that "San Francisco" is a city in the above sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The task of recognising possibly multi-word expressions that reference individuals of various specific types (locations, but also organisations, dates, etc.) is called [named-entity recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) (NER).

For a simple task such as yours, existing freely available tools and models are sufficient. You could try the [Stanford Named Entity Recognizer,](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) which is free software. Try analysing your sentence using their [online demo.](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/)