# nlp - How to detect if a word in a sentence is pointing to a color/body part /vehicle

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, wordnet, lexical-analysis, named-entity-recognition

So as the title suggests I would like to know if a certain word in a sentence is pointing to

1] A color

```
The grass is green.
```

Hence "green" is color

2] A body part

```
Her hands are soft
```

Hence "hands" is a body part

3] A vehicle

```
I am driving my car on the causeway
```

Hence "car" is a vehicle

In similar problems, parsers are one of the possible effective solutions.
Stanford parser for example was suggested to a similar question

[How to find if a word in a sentence is pointing to a city](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397698/how-to-find-if-a-word-in-a-sentence-is-pointing-to-a-city)

Now the problem is that stanford parser can be used to detect:

```
LOCATION
ORGANIZATION
DATE
MONEY
PERSON
PERCENT
TIME
```

However if you would like to try to detect something else, word-net might be an option as mentioned in a similar question

[How do I list out all English terms in a sentence that indicate an animal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072775/how-do-i-list-out-all-english-terms-in-a-sentence-that-indicate-an-animal)

One of the answers suggested using wordnet and leveraging the hyponym/hypernym relation. The answer also mentioned the noun.animal file of wordnet.

The link below shows a list of all other files in wordnet
https://wordnet.princeton.edu/man/lexnames.5WN.html

My approach is that I can make use of

1]

```
(noun.body FOR body parts)
```

2]

```
(noun.artifact FOR vehicles)
```

3]

```
 The (hyponym/hypernym) relationship can be used to detect if word is pointing to a color or not.
```

So would that be a valid approach ?

And how can I make use of the (hyponym/hypernym) is wordnet ?

NOTE: I'am planning to use: JWI (the MIT Java Wordnet Interface)

Comment: You should use the "*Named-Entity Recognition* (NER)" keyword to find more information.

Comment: For colors, you should make your own lexicon manually (or find a lexicon on Internet). There are not so much colors and it would be more reliable.

Comment: @clemtoy What would the NER add that wordnet can't add ?

Comment: @clemtoy what would you recommend as a source for all list of colors ?

Comment: NER is not a tool, it is the name of your problem. I just would like to point out that your problem is known as "NER problem" so that you should find more information.
You can make a lexicon of colors parsing [this wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors_(compact)). (Sorry I can't tag your name in my comment as it fails)

Comment: @clemtoy If I am not mistaken Stanford nlp tries to solve that problem. The question is what about the classes it doesn't recognize. So it recognize places but what about vehicles for example

Comment: @clemtoy and regarding the color list in wikipedia, it might be useful. But if  a word like reddish is used, how can I detect it. Can wordnet be used here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83024/discussion-between-clemtoy-and-abdel-rahman-shoman).

Comment: NER is a sophisticated technique which can be used to handle these kind of problems. Consider this as an example "Robert Green was driving a blue car." If you use a lexicon, you would probably end up tagging green and blue as colors but in reality green here is not a color. NER classifiers can learn to tag words given their context. So for your use case, I would advice building a NER classifier of your own to handle any class you want.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the *hyponymy / hypernymy* approach, this would involve exploring the wordnet tree and its relations between words.

The **hyponyms** of a word (of a *Synset*, to be more accurate) represent concepts which are more particular in nature, while **hypernyms** represent concepts more general in nature. As an analogy with the tree-like structure of Wordnet, you could view the hyponyms as *children* of the word (*node*) you are looking at, with hypernyms being *parents* of that word.

As an example, taking the hyponyms and the hypernyms of the word *dog*:

```
dog = wn.synsets('dog')[0]
print(dog.hypernyms())
print(dog.hyponyms())
```

yields the following results:

```
[Synset('canine.n.02'), Synset('domestic_animal.n.01')]

[Synset('basenji.n.01'), Synset('corgi.n.01'), Synset('cur.n.01'), 
Synset('dalmatian.n.02'), Synset('great_pyrenees.n.01'), S 
Synset('griffon.n.02'), Synset('hunting_dog.n.01'), Synset('lapdog.n.01'), 
Synset('leonberg.n.01'), Synset('mexican_hairless.n.01'), 
Synset('newfoundland.n.01'), Synset('pooch.n.01'), Synset('poodle.n.01'), 
Synset('pug.n.01'), Synset('puppy.n.01'), Synset('spitz.n.01'), 
Synset('toy_dog.n.01'), Synset('working_dog.n.01')]
```

In a similar manner, if we wanted for example to know which words represent colours, we could explore the hypernyms of different words representing colours, hoping that they would have a common ancestor (hypernym). In this sense, I have done the following experiments:

```
print(wn.synsets('green')[0].hypernyms())
print(wn.synsets('blue')[0].hypernyms())
print(wn.synsets('red')[0].hypernyms())
print(wn.synsets('yellow')[0].hypernyms())
```

all of which share the same hypernym list:

```
[Synset('chromatic_color.n.01')]
```

Also

```
print(wn.synsets('black')[0].hypernyms())
print(wn.synsets('gray')[0].hypernyms())
```

yield the result

```
[Synset('achromatic_color.n.01')]
```

Next thing we can do is print all the hyponyms of these resulting synsets:

```
print(wn.synset('chromatic_color.n.01').hyponyms())
print(wn.synset('chromatic_color.n.01').hyponyms())
```

which give the results

```
[Synset('blond.n.02'), Synset('blue.n.01'), Synset('brown.n.01'), 
Synset('complementary_color.n.01'), Synset('green.n.01'), 
Synset('olive.n.05'), Synset('orange.n.02'), Synset('pastel.n.01'), 
Synset('pink.n.01'), Synset('purple.n.01'), Synset('red.n.01'), 
Synset('salmon.n.04'), Synset('yellow.n.01')]

[Synset('black.n.01'), Synset('gray.n.01'), Synset('white.n.02')]
```

The same technique could be applied to explore options relating to *body parts* or *vehicles*.

Also, in the case of derivative words such as *reddish*, there are two methods of bypassing their absence that I know of:

- **Stemming** the tokenized text, by means of *Porter Stemmer* (see [this link](http://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html))
- Using **Morphy** to get the base forms, letting you look up the resulting words in Wordnet (see [this link](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) for details on Morphy). I would recommend this method, since stemming could potentially yield words which do not exist in Wordnet