# How to detect if a sentence is pointing to particular defined concepts

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, lexical-analysis, pattern-recognition

How can I detect if a particular sentence is pointing to particular defined concepts such as:

`Start`:

E.g. “Can we begin” or “Let’s start”

`Definition`:

E.g. “Define (a word)” or “What does (a word) mean” or “Meaning of (a word)”

In the first case the sentences point to the concept “to start,” and in the second example, the sentences point to the concept of a `definition`.

So how do I identify these concepts in a sentence. A similar question to mine is 
[nlp - How to detect if a word in a sentence is pointing to a color/body part /vehicle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355225/nlp-how-to-detect-if-a-word-in-a-sentence-is-pointing-to-a-color-body-part-ve)

I used Stanford’s NLP API to make a Name Entity Recognizer class, but it can only detect

```
LOCATION
ORGANIZATION
DATE
MONEY
PERSON
PERCENT
TIME
```

Here is the code:

```
public void NER() throws ClassCastException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException
{
    String serializedClassifier = "english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
    AbstractSequenceClassifier<CoreLabel> classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifier(serializedClassifier);
    int i=0;
      String PER = "";
      String LOC = "";
      String TIME = "";
      String DATE = "";
      String ORG = "";
      for (String str : toComputeOn) {
        for (List<CoreLabel> lcl : classifier.classify(str)) {
          for (CoreLabel cl : lcl) {
            System.out.print(i++ + ": ");
            System.out.println(cl.toShorterString());

            if(cl.get(CoreAnnotations.AnswerAnnotation.class).equals("TIME"))
                TIME += "\n"+ cl.toString();
            if(cl.get(CoreAnnotations.AnswerAnnotation.class).equals("PERSON"))
                PER += "\n"+ cl.toString();
            if(cl.get(CoreAnnotations.AnswerAnnotation.class).equals("ORGANIZATION"))
                ORG += "\n"+ cl.toString();
            if(cl.get(CoreAnnotations.AnswerAnnotation.class).equals("DATE"))
                DATE += "\n"+ cl.toString();
            if(cl.get(CoreAnnotations.AnswerAnnotation.class).equals("LOCATION"))
                LOC += "\n"+ cl.toString();
          }
        }
      }

      if(!PER.equals("")) {
          System.out.println("PERSON: "+ PER);
          System.out.println("---");
      }
      if(!ORG.equals("")) {
          System.out.println("ORGANIZATION: "+ ORG);
          System.out.println("---");
      }
      if(!LOC.equals("")) {
          System.out.println("LOCATION: "+ LOC);
          System.out.println("---");
      }
      if(!TIME.equals("")) {
          System.out.println("TIME: "+ TIME);
          System.out.println("---");
      }
      if(!DATE.equals(""))
          System.out.println("DATE: "+ DATE);
}
```

I need something that can detect other concepts. I was looking through Stanford’s API and found the BasicRelationExtractor class. I am not 100% sure what it does, but would using this class help me solve my problem, OR would it be better for me to train my own NER Classifier, OR would it be better to use MIT’s Java Wordnet Interface?

Thanks for any help

Comment: If you have a small set of predefined concepts, then training your own NER is the best way to go.

Comment: Ok. So would I train these models with specific key words such as `definition` , `meaning`, `start`, `begin`?

Comment: There are potentially hundreds of ways to train a model like this, including different ways to do feature selection. A discussion - even just for an overview - on this topic is much beyond the scope of SO. My advice is to invest some time into reading and understanding some research papers on NER (particularly the publications from the Stanford NLP team).

Comment: @Chthonic Project Ok, I will read their research papers. Thanks

Comment: Maybe [Google Word2Vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/) could help you as it provides a distance between words depending on their meaning.

Comment: Thank you @clemtoy. Isn't Google's Word2Vec based on C? Is there something like Google's Word2Vec in Stanford's NLP API? Thank you so much

Comment: I don't know, but [Deeplearning4j](http://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec.html) seems to provide an interface of Word2Vec for java.

Comment: Thanks @clemont. I will look into this